# VBA: Can't change Image Control picture after click on element

Tags: vba, excel, userform

**Setup**

I have an Excel VBA UserForm with an Image Control element. When clicking on buttons in the form, the Image Control's `Picture` source is set / updated with the following code:

```
Set MyForm.imgControl.Picture = LoadPicture(pathToFile)
```

**Problem**

When the user clicks on the Image Control, updating its `Picture` source doesn't work anymore. The problem occurs, no matter when in the workflow the Image Control is clicked:

- Example 1: User clicks a button to set the Picture (and pictures sets correctly). User clicks on Image Control. User clicks a different button to change the Picture -> displayed picture doesn't change.
- Example 2: User clicks on Image Control right after Form load. User clicks on button to change the Picture -> displayed picture doesn't change.

If the user never clicks on the Image Control, everything works perfectly smoothly. It's worth noting that clicking on the Image Control doesn't visibly focus it.

**Question**

Clicking on the Image Control shouldn't make a difference in whether or not the Picture can be updated or not. How can this be done? Or, at least, does anyone know why the explained behavior is happening, or is it just a bug?

The Control does have Click / MouseDown / ... events (which are empty), but they don't take a Cancel parameter.

Comment: Does it help if you `Repaint` the form after loading the picture?

Comment: With VBA it can sometimes be quite difficult to figure out if things are bugs or "features". Have you tried to make a function which clears the `imgControl` first, instead of adding a new image?

Comment: @Rory Good idea! Adding a `MyForm.Repaint` after loading the picture works. Feel free to add your comment as an answer and I'll at least give it a +1. Still hoping someone will figure out the underlying reason for this.

Comment: @Noceo: Clearing the control (`Set MyForm.imgControl.Picture = Nothing`) doesn't help.

Comment: Btw, @Rory: Repainting before loading the picture also works - except the very first time when there is no picture set yet - seems more and more like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does sound like a bug, as you say, but as a workaround, I'd suggest forcing a repaint after changing the picture:

```
Set MyForm.imgControl.Picture = LoadPicture(pathToFile)
MyForm.Repaint
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding that resizing my Image control did the trick (i.e. increasing and then immediately decreasing the width before adding the picture).