# How to show excel sheet chart in excel VBA userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with two controls. One combobox called `ComboBox1` and an image called `image1`. I am trying to show a chart on a sheet to this `image1` during `ComboBox1` change event as below

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Call UpdateChart
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateChart()

Dim sTempFile As String
Dim oChart As Chart

sTempFile = Environ("temp") & "\temp.gif"

Set oChart = Worksheets(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

oChart.Export Filename:=sTempFile, FilterName:="GIF"

UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(sTempFile)

Kill sTempFile

End Sub
```

This is working perfectly fine. But once I clicked on the image, `ComboBox1` change event is not working anymore. In other words, the chart is not changing according to combobox change if I clicked on the image. Does anyone know why?
PS: I took the above code from some other site and modified to suit my needs.

**Edit 1**

`ComboBox1` populating as below during `Userform` initialization.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With UserForm1.ComboBox1
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "MainPage", "Raw Data"

            Case Else
                .AddItem ws.Name
        End Select
    Next ws
End With
End Sub
```

`ComboBox1` values are the sheet names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - adding `Me.Repaint` fixed it for me

```
Private Sub UpdateChart()

    Dim sTempFile As String
    Dim oChart As Chart

    sTempFile = Environ("temp") & "\temp.gif"

    Set oChart = Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

    oChart.Export Filename:=sTempFile, FilterName:="GIF"

    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(sTempFile)

    Me.Repaint   '<<<<<

    Kill sTempFile

End Sub
```

FYI within a form's code it's better to use `Me` instead of (eg) `UserForm1` - that way you can rename the form if you need without having to edit all the code.

Comment: This perfectly works. But do you know why when I click on the image, it is not updating chart anymore without this `Repaint`?

Comment: Who knows?  Previously - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267087/vba-cant-change-image-control-picture-after-click-on-element